# clicking a button in infowindow causes map click to register on google maps api v3

Tags: onclick, maps, infowindow

i have an infowindow that has an "erase entry" button, that when clicked, removes the marker and closes the info window.
when i click the "erase entry" button, it removes the marker and closes the infowindow just fine, but it also registers another click on map, and i have no idea why, and it's driving me nuts.

has anyone bumped into this problem before?
i'm quite a noob at javascript, so any suggestions on implementation would be great too. thank.
below's pseudocode/summary of what i'm doing:

```
        //global variable to keep track of which was the last marker clicked
        var lastMarkerJustClicked;

        function load(){
            //create the map and everything, add the following listener
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                //firebug has been telling me that after i click "erase entry" and my marker is removed and my infowindow closes, i end up here
                makeParticularMarker(event.latLng);
            });
        }

        function makeParticularMarker(marker_parameter) {
            var markerLocation = //do stuff to get the right marker parameter
            var markerWithLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerLocation,
                map: map
            }); 
            var html = "<input type='button' value='Erase Entry' onclick=eraseEntry() />"
            var markerWithInfo = createMarkerWithHTML(markerWithLocation, html);
        }

        function createMarkerWithHTML(markerWithLocation, html) {
            var markerWithInfo = google.maps.event.addListener(markerWithLocation, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, markerWithLocation)
                lastMarkerJustClicked=markerWithLocation;
            });
        }

        function eraseEntry() {
            infoWindow.close()
            lastMarkerJustClicked.setMap(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/221876cc70bea9c6?pli=1

it has to do with propagation. and you stop it by doing something like this

```
function doSomething(e)
{
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

this site gives a better explanation about this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html